# Getting the count programmatically for ui-grid group

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

Given a grouping in `ui-grid`, how can I programmatically get the count (shown parenthetically and highlighted in screenshot)?

The end goal here is adding a (custom) menu item that sorts a column by count of groups.

[image]

Comment: Can You add data example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone here can find a way to do this directly thru the ui-grid API, I'd suggest you to simply do a lodash _.groupBy on the json used to build the grid. Let me know if u need help with that and I'll expand on it.

Comment: Way to think outside the box (or API, as it were). Didn't even consider that. Thanks!